# SQL Script that saves file to location other than server using xp_cmdshell bcp queryout

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I have code that saves an `.xml` file to the server, but I need it to be saved to a fileshare location.

```
DECLARE @Command VARCHAR(255) 
DECLARE @Filename VARCHAR(100) 
SELECT  @Filename = 'd:\TestXMLRoutine.xml' 
SELECT @Command = 'bcp "select xCol from ' + 
DB_NAME() + '..MyXMLTable" queryout ' + 
@Filename + ' -w -T -S' + @@servername 
EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell @Command
```

Instead of saving the file to the local drive (D:), I need to save it to a fileshare such as `\\file-server\`. However, I'm having trouble getting this to work. When I try to change the file location, I encounter errors or null values.

Comment: Please write the query and errors you got

Comment: When i change the @FileName like the below to lets say '\\file-server\TestXMLRoutine.xml' vs 'd:\TestXMLRoutine.xml' i get this error SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0 Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Unable to open BCP host data-file

Comment: Well, does your sql server have access to the share

Comment: If you run the command manually in cmd, does it work there

Comment: It worked from cmd WTH!  Must be missing something in my Query?

Comment: It's permissions then

Comment: That was it, it was my permissions thanks for pointing me in the right direction!